# How to list files part of a BTRFS block?

Tags: btrfs

On my BTRFS filesystem, I have a problem with block id #43231330304.

`BTRFS critical (device sda2): corrupt leaf, slot offset bad: block=43231330304,root=1, slot=47`

I want to know which files are part of this block. How to do this?

Comment: `find /mount-point -type f -exec cp {} /dev/null \;` seems an option, see http://superuser.com/questions/858237/finding-files-with-btrfs-uncorrectable-errors

Answer (score 3):

To identify the corrupted files, first run:

`btrfs scrub status /mount-point`

then check the path in `dmesg`:

`BTRFS: i/o error at logical 167135232000 on dev /dev/sda2, sector 213189792, root 5, inode 2963892, offset 7700480, length 4096, links 1 (path: /home/foo...)`

Comment: It seems like you have to first start a scrub via `btrfs scrub start /mount-point`.